# WSDL SOAP REQUEST

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am new to Soap and PHP i have a requirment of making an request to An Soap end point and reading xml response

```
SoapEndpoint = http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/irfanshafi/WCOM?wsdl
Method: GetArchivedDocument
```

i have a sample request provided which is as

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
      xmlns:dcom="http://172.16.4.16:790/AlghanimAutoline/WCOM">
      <soapenv:Body>
      <dcom:GetArchivedDocument>
      <dcom:Identification>
      <dcom:SessionId>10000005</dcom:SessionId>
      </dcom:Identification>
      <dcom:LookupCodes>
       <dcom:RooftopId>TABYAAS01</dcom:RooftopId>
    <dcom:DocRef>WI03274714</dcom:DocRef>
    <dcom:Terminal>1021</dcom:Terminal>
    </dcom:LookupCodes>
    </dcom:GetArchivedDocument>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>`

i would appreciate if someone can guide how can i implement this and read the xml response.
i have to create a soap request with the end point i am just confused with how can i pass the request body parameters or what would be the convienient way to implement such request.

Comment: Have you tried using SoapClient already? https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: yes i have , i just have little doubt that how can i pass these parameters sample request paramets

Comment: Use `SoapClient::__soapCall`. You pass argument as an array. Mind the order of arguments.